# How to get a button to select a random name from a list

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a list with names. These names are linked to a label. When I click the label a name at random designated for that label is selected.

What I need is for when a button is clicked, it selects a random name for each label.

for example;

I have 5 names in a list and each individual list is linked to an individual label. One name will be selected for a label at random. I need all 10 of my labels to select a random name, when a button is clicked.

Hope that makes sense. I am using Visual Studio 2010 and c# on a form. Many Thanks

So this is what I have. This is part of the code I need (dont worry with what its about). The goalkeeper label is called "goalkeeper" my button should be called "pickTeam" but when clicked shows up as "button1_Click" `private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`

I need it so that when the button clicked, every label (I can do myself once figured out) will choose a random name that has been given. I.E; Begovic, De Gea etc etc.

i have a method for each position. This is the Goalkeeper, once I know this I can do it for the other positions. Thanks

```
private void goalkeeper_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            List<string> goalkeepers = new List<string>();
            goalkeepers.Add("Neuer");
            goalkeepers.Add("De Gea");
            goalkeepers.Add("Lloris");
            goalkeepers.Add("Begovic");
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                int index = rand.Next(0, 4);
                goalkeeper.Text = goalkeepers[index];
            }
        }
```

Comment: I guess your current code works? What extra you need/what issue(s) you are facing?

Comment: You don't need the for loop and you can put the List init outside of the click button. For the random part, it's better if you use rand.Next(0, goalkeepers.Length) so that in future if you want to add more goal keepers ,you don't need to alter the code.

Comment: I wont need to add the code this is only a 1 time used thing but need it correct haha. Yeah this code currently is link to a label. So a label on my form will show up a random name when clicked, however I wish that when the button is clicked it will choose the random players for all positions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Order your `goalkeepers` list by a new `Guid` to a get a random order, then pick the first:

```
private void SetLabelText(Label label, List<string> names)
{
    var randomName = names.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).FirstOrDefault();
    label.Text = randomName;
}
```

You could call this for each of your labels e.g:

```
private void SetupLabels()
{
     SetLabelText(label1, goalkeepers);
     SetLabelText(label2, goalkeepers);
     SetLabelText(label3, goalkeepers);
     SetLabelText(label4, goalkeepers);
     SetLabelText(label5, goalkeepers);
}

private void goalkeeper_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     SetupLabels();
}
```

But to be honest, there isn't a lot wrong with what you already have

Comment: Would this then allow it so that when I click a button, all labels will show a random name from said list? I have 5 different names for each label. I have 11 labels

Comment: Yes, see my edit. Just pass in each label as a parameter to `SetLabelText` and provide the list of names for each one.

Comment: I think I get it. So I keep my Goalkeeper_click like that with the names?

Then with label 1 maybe being called goalkeeper, 
label 2 being defender, 
label 3 being mid etc?

in goalkeeper_click i only need 'setuplabels'

where do I put the names I wish it to choose from?

Comment: You state here `I have 5 names in a list and each individual list is linked to an individual label`. Does each label actually have its own list? If not the `SetLabelText()` function can define the names itself rather than these being passed in as a parameter. Yes call the labels whatever you like, and yes call `SetupLabels()` in your button click event handler.

Comment: Yeah each label does so my goalkeeper has those 4 players, my rightback has 4 more players etc. all players are different and the same player can never be chose twice.

Comment: Yes, in that case the code above is fine. Just provide a new list of player names to each call to `SetLabelText()` along with the label. If this answers your question, please consider [accepting it as the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: @T.Fensom No worries, happy to help.